# How to have a class method be a generator function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm learning about ES6 generator functions as well as classes. I'm trying to combine them but don't know *if* you can, and how. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```js
class Container {
  constructor(names) {
    this._names = names;
  }
  
  // Won't work:
  //itemsWith*(part) {
  //  for (const name of this._names) {
  //    if (name.includes(part)) yield name;
  //  }
  //}
  
  // Workaround:
  itemsWithPartGeneratorFunc(part) {
    const capturedNames = this._names;
    function* itemsWith() {
      for (const name of capturedNames) {
        if (name.includes(part)) yield name;
      }
    }    
    return itemsWith;
  }
}

const group = new Container(['blue dragon', 'red tiger', 'green tiger']);

// Won't work:
// for (const name of group.itemsWith('tiger')) { console.log(name); }

// Workaround:
for (const name of group.itemsWithPartGeneratorFunc('tiger')()) { console.log(name); }
```

I understand that in my contrived example above it is complete overkill, but I'm trying to learn so I must ask: is there a syntax to make the first option work?

Comment: Ugh, not only a duplicate, but also just a minor syntax mistake. Apparently the `*` goes in front of the name. TIL. - Will leave my question up here to help with SEO for those that phrased their issue similar to my phrasing.